# Laravel - adminlte.php doesn't recognize Auth::id()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've downloaded and installed adminlte package to create a admin panel template for me. The panel is working well, I've already built a lot of functionalities but i can't manage to send a variable to a route. Example:

In adminlte.php you build the side-menu like:

[image]

The view gets:

[image]

But when i click in the **'Perfil'** section it doesn't recognize the `Auth::id()`, it treats it as a String instead of the actual logged user's id. The error I get:

[image]

I tried adding `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;` to both adminlte.php and controller but still doesn't work.

Route:

```
// Middleware to check if user is Admin
  Route::group(['middleware' => 'Admin'], function() {

     Route::group(['prefix' => '/perfil'], function() {
        Route::get('/{id}', 'AdminPanelController@getProfile');
      });

   });
```

getProfile method:

```
public function getProfile($id) {
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);
    return view("admin_panel.info_views.users.user_profile")->with("user", $user);
  }
```

adminlte.php:

```
<?php


return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Title
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The default title of your admin panel, this goes into the title tag
    | of your page. You can override it per page with the title section.
    | You can optionally also specify a title prefix and/or postfix.
    |
    */

    'title' => 'AdminLTE 2',

    'title_prefix' => '',

    'title_postfix' => '',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Logo
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This logo is displayed at the upper left corner of your admin panel.
    | You can use basic HTML here if you want. The logo has also a mini
    | variant, used for the mini side bar. Make it 3 letters or so
    |
    */

    'logo' => '<b>UNIK</b>HB',

    'logo_mini' => '<b>U</b>NK',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Skin Color
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Choose a skin color for your admin panel. The available skin colors:
    | blue, black, purple, yellow, red, and green. Each skin also has a
    | ligth variant: blue-light, purple-light, purple-light, etc.
    |
    */

    'skin' => 'yellow',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Layout
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Choose a layout for your admin panel. The available layout options:
    | null, 'boxed', 'fixed', 'top-nav'. null is the default, top-nav
    | removes the sidebar and places your menu in the top navbar
    |
    */

    'layout' => null,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Collapse Sidebar
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here we choose and option to be able to start with a collapsed side
    | bar. To adjust your sidebar layout simply set this  either true
    | this is compatible with layouts except top-nav layout option
    |
    */

    'collapse_sidebar' => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | URLs
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Register here your dashboard, logout, login and register URLs. The
    | logout URL automatically sends a POST request in Laravel 5.3 or higher.
    | You can set the request to a GET or POST with logout_method.
    | Set register_url to null if you don't want a register link.
    |
    */

    'dashboard_url' => 'home',

    'logout_url' => 'logout',

    'logout_method' => null,

    'login_url' => 'login',

    'register_url' => 'register',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Menu Items
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Specify your menu items to display in the left sidebar. Each menu item
    | should have a text and and a URL. You can also specify an icon from
    | Font Awesome. A string instead of an array represents a header in sidebar
    | layout. The 'can' is a filter on Laravel's built in Gate functionality.
    |
    */

    'menu' => [
        'NAVEGAÇÃO PRINCIPAL',
        [
            'text' => 'Blog',
            'url'  => 'admin/blog',
            'can'  => 'manage-blog',
        ],
        [
            'text'        => 'Painel principal',
            'url'         => 'admin/painel',
            'icon'        => 'dashboard',
        ],
        [
            'text'    => 'Editar páginas',
            'icon'    => 'edit',
            'submenu' => [
                [
                    'text' => 'Vantagens',
                    'url'  => 'admin/editar_paginas/vantagens',
                    'icon_color' => 'purple',
                ],
                [
                    'text' => 'Dúvidas frequentes',
                    'url'  => "#",
                    'icon_color' => 'green',
                    'submenu' => [
                        [
                            'text' => 'Ver dúvidas/respostas',
                            'url'  => 'admin/editar_paginas/duvidas',
                            'icon_color' => 'green',
                        ],
                        [
                            'text' => 'Inserir dúvida/resposta',
                            'url'  => 'admin/editar_paginas/inserir_duvida',
                            'icon_color' => 'green',
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                [
                    'text' => 'Equipe',
                    'url'  => "#",
                    'icon_color' => 'blue',
                    'submenu' => [
                        [
                            'text' => 'Ver equipe',
                            'url'  => 'admin/editar_paginas/equipe',
                            'icon_color' => 'blue',
                        ],
                        [
                            'text' => 'Inserir funcionário',
                            'url'  => 'admin/editar_paginas/inserir_funcionario',
                            'icon_color' => 'blue',
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                [
                    'text'    => 'Tabela de Honorários',
                    'url'     => '#',
                    'icon_color' => 'orange',
                    'submenu' => [
                        [
                            'text' => 'Editar tabela',
                            'url'  => 'admin/editar_paginas/editar_tabela_honorarios',
                            'icon_color' => 'orange',
                        ],
                        [
                            'text' => 'Editar texto da tabela',
                            'url'  => 'admin/editar_paginas/editar_texto_tabela_honorarios',
                            'icon_color' => 'orange',
                        ],
                        [
                            'text' => 'Inserir honorários',
                            'url'  => 'admin/editar_paginas/inserir_honorario',
                            'icon_color' => 'orange',
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                [
                    'text' => 'Level One',
                    'url'  => '#',
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'CONFIGURAÇÕES DA CONTA',
        [
            'text' => 'Perfil',
            'url' => 'admin/perfil'.\Auth::user()->id,
            'icon' => 'user',
        ],
        [
            'text' => 'Alterar senha',
            'url'  => 'admin/settings',
            'icon' => 'lock',
        ],
        'LABELS',
        [
            'text'       => 'Important',
            'icon_color' => 'red',
        ],
        [
            'text'       => 'Warning',
            'icon_color' => 'yellow',
        ],
        [
            'text'       => 'Information',
            'icon_color' => 'aqua',
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Menu Filters
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Choose what filters you want to include for rendering the menu.
    | You can add your own filters to this array after you've created them.
    | You can comment out the GateFilter if you don't want to use Laravel's
    | built in Gate functionality
    |
    */

    'filters' => [
        JeroenNoten\LaravelAdminLte\Menu\Filters\HrefFilter::class,
        JeroenNoten\LaravelAdminLte\Menu\Filters\ActiveFilter::class,
        JeroenNoten\LaravelAdminLte\Menu\Filters\SubmenuFilter::class,
        JeroenNoten\LaravelAdminLte\Menu\Filters\ClassesFilter::class,
        JeroenNoten\LaravelAdminLte\Menu\Filters\GateFilter::class,
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Plugins Initialization
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Choose which JavaScript plugins should be included. At this moment,
    | only DataTables is supported as a plugin. Set the value to true
    | to include the JavaScript file from a CDN via a script tag.
    |
    */

    'plugins' => [
        'datatables' => true,
    ],
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was not to pass the id trough URL but change the controller method.

From:

`public function getProfile($id) {
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);
    return view("admin_panel.info_views.users.user_profile")->with("user", $user);
  }`

To:

`public function getProfile() {
    $user = Auth::user();
    return view("admin_panel.info_views.users.user_profile")->with("user", $user);
  }`

Also changed the route to not receive a parameter. This way i managed to access user info without needing to pass their id trough URL which is where i had been having trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is within the quotes. Change it to:

```
'url' => 'admin/perfil'.\Auth::user()->id
```

Comment: Did this and for some reason it breaks the entire application lol cant access any page (put the ',' in the end).
Gives: [link](https://image.prntscr.com/image/pKgD4dv-QkCpwLYfeqz_Ug.png)

Comment: @Diego Can you please, turn on the debugging and paste the full exception?

Comment: It is on! Only when I do this piece of code that it doesn't show anything. I don't know why. My .env has APP_DEBUG=true.

Comment: That's strange. Can you please post the full spinet of that array?

Comment: I see... can you try to remove the backslash? `'url' => 'admin/perfil'.Auth::user()->id` another idea will be to place the integer instead of user id, 1 for example, if it works then the problem is with the auth class and we can dig in deeper

Comment: Just tried with an integer and works... it returns me the view with my user info. Tried removing the backslash and it gives the same weird bug without any exception. When i put like `'url' => 'admin/perfil'.Auth::user()->id` all of the app pages (not only the admin panel) is inaccessible. Is there anyway i could pass a variable to adminlte.php?

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't used this package. From what I see, it a simple associative array, which has no access to Laravel's auth class. I'd recommend to store the user id in session and use it in the above mentioned assoc array

Comment: Well i've found a way out, instead of passing the ID trough the URL in the controller i simply do:

`public function getProfile() {
    return view("admin_panel.info_views.users.user_profile")->with("user", Auth::user());
  }`

It has the same result but only doesn't show the Auth id in the route. I think thats good to go...